# problem with Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am using kde neaon plasma 5
When I go to one folder in home for example : Music and then going back to first page ( home ), all folders selected. I do not know why.!!??

I will attach a pic about it.
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtOo1.png)
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OkZ0.png)

If you have any Idea please inform me .
thanks

Comment: Do you use *KDE neon* or *Kubuntu*?

Comment: I am using KDE neon ;-)

Comment: I solved the issue . you could help me anyway instead bringing some excuse.  Hope you do for others. first helping them and then inform them about rules

Comment: Its not an excuse. There is a mandate in **Ask Ubuntu** to ask questions about *Ubuntu* so answers are narrow in scope and targeted to a specific audience. Its nothing personal.

Comment: I know you are right but , I am not the only person who asked something which is not relate to ubuntu - have a look pls.                                     
      https://askubuntu.com/search?q=kde+neon[link]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok This problem might be happens for **KUBUNTU**

So if anybody has this problem there is solution for that.

This problem will happens if you sort your folders by ***Rating***
to solve this issue just sort them by name or something else except rating

Comment: I don't know why one stupid person gave me negative ( not plus ) . Yeah it is not personal. It is clear